# In ASP.Net MVC (4 or 5) is it possible to add a custom authorize event without having a custom authorize attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I want to add a custom step to the process which happens when the [Authorize] attribute is encountered by a request to an action. I would rather not redecorate all my actions with a custom version of the authorize attribute.

I am hoping there is something like this:

```
Global.OnAuthorize += () => { /*do stuff*/ };
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using FormsAuthentication, you might want to add to your Global.asax a method called `FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate`, which is used as a [FormAuthentication EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.security.formsauthenticationeventhandler(v=vs.100).aspx).

> The FormsAuthenticationEventHandler delegate is defined for the
>   Authenticate event of the FormsAuthenticationModule class. You can
>   access the Authenticate event of the FormsAuthenticationModule class
>   by specifying a subroutine named FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate in
>   the Global.asax file for your ASP.NET application. The Authenticate
>   event is raised during the AuthenticateRequest event.

The [AuthenticateEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule.authenticate(v=vs.100).aspx) is raised during the AuthenticateRequest

> The AuthenticateRequest event signals that the configured
>   authentication mechanism has authenticated the current request.
>   Subscribing to the AuthenticateRequest event ensures that the request
>   will be authenticated before processing the attached module or event
>   handler

```
public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(
            Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This event seems to execute every time any Action is hit. Is there some way to tell, in this context, whether this event was fired as a result of hitting an Action which was decorated with an Authorize attribute?

Comment: You might be able to get the decoration attributes of the action using reflection. I've done it before for models, but it should be something similar

Comment: I think this could be marked an the answer if the reflection idea could be proven.

Answer (score 1):

> I would rather not redecorate all my actions with a custom version of the authorize attribute.

You can just apply your custom authorization attribute globally.

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MyCustomAuthorizationAttribute());
```

After that you can use **AllowAnonymous** attribute to decorate actions or controllers you want to be used without authorization.

Comment: This would still require me to rearrange my Attribute decorations to something non-standard. I would prefer to able to continue to support fully anonymous controllers by having no decoration.

Comment: @JordanMorris you want to have your cake and to it it at the same time. That's not possible. Either you decorate all with `[Authorize]` or decorate some with `[AllowAnonymous]`. Nothing is wrong with having  attributes on your controllers.